# Remove a numeric value along with the word after that numeric value in a String

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove a numeric value plus the words after it.

I have some Strings like this. When I perform my Regex, it only removes the numeric value. But the words after that value is not removed. I want the words after that to be deleted as well.

Before: Strings :

> E.g.
>
> APPLEJUICE2.4L
>
> GreenAppleJuice1L
>
> HALVEDPEACHES415g
>
> IceyChocIceCream60ml

After: Strings:

> E.g.
>
> APPLEJUICE
>
> GreenAppleJuice
>
> HALVEDPEACHES
>
> IceyChocIceCream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
String repl = input.replaceFirst("\\d\\S*", "");
```

i.e. find a first digit in input and match every non-space character after that.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zE8eY9/1)